# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' - error

Tags: python, django, memcached, celery, python-memcached

I have python-memcached (1.57) and django-celery (3.1.17), celery (3.1.20) and python 3.5. I always get the error below when i try to implement http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time

```
Task tasks.live_task[a2ed1faf-0fce-4855-a206-40f2fbdae1a8] raised unexpected: TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/current/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/current/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/current/src/helps.py", line 62, in wrapper
if acquire():
File "/app/current/src/helps.py", line 57, in acquire
return cache.add(id, "true", time_out)
File "/app/current/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 80, in add
return self._cache.add(key, value, self.get_backend_timeout(timeout))
File "/app/current/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/memcache.py", line 633, in add
return self._set("add", key, val, time, min_compress_len, noreply)
File "/app/current/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/memcache.py", line 983, in _set
server, key = self._get_server(key)
File "/app/dashboard/current/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/memcache.py", line 413, in _get_server
serverhash = serverHashFunction(str(serverhash) + str(i))
File "/app/current/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/memcache.py", line 65, in cmemcache_hash
(((binascii.crc32(key) & 0xffffffff)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: The error is most likely related to your python version. Try converting to bytes by using `bytes(string, encoding="UTF-8")`.

Comment: Try using `python3-memcached`

Comment: @DerekKwok `python3-memcached>=1.51` or is anchoring to 1.51 specifically important?

Comment: @tdelaney I've removed the version number, there's no specific reason to use only version 1.51-

Answer (score 4):

`python-memchached` is not supported on `python 3.5`
If you've used `python-memchached`, The following commands will help you.

```
pip uninstall python-memcached
pip install python3-memcached
```

Comment: actually it's a trap. python3-memcached does work but it's discontinued and the official python-memcached only works with utf-8 encoded data. Supposedly there's a fix for it but for me it still blows up: https://github.com/linsomniac/python-memcached/issues/80

Comment: That's right. python3-memcached is deprecated. It was just  a py3 compatibility port of python-memcached which since then has added py23.